# How do I solve an error rising when I try installing pyodbc using pip in cmd

Tags: python

I am getting an error when I try to install `pyodbc` on a `Windows` computer using `cmd`.

```
C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310>python.exe -m pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.32.tar.gz (280 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyodbc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pcyber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w2t0bax7\\pyodbc_0972efc851a7442b9e86edce259cfc8a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pcyber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w2t0bax7\\pyodbc_0972efc851a7442b9e86edce259cfc8a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xbgtptdk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\pyodbc'
         cwd: C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w2t0bax7\pyodbc_0972efc851a7442b9e86edce259cfc8a\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pcyber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w2t0bax7\\pyodbc_0972efc851a7442b9e86edce259cfc8a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pcyber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w2t0bax7\\pyodbc_0972efc851a7442b9e86edce259cfc8a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xbgtptdk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\pyodbc' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is trying to compile `pyodbc` from source but you do not have any compiler installed on your computer. There usually are binary packages which do not need to be compiled but there is none for your python version (3.10).

You should either downgrade to an older version of python such as 3.9 or follow the instructions given by the error which is to install the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

According to that part of the error message:

```
extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

It looks like you are missing a suitable C++ compiler on your platform.
According to the documentation of pyodbc you require one:

> Note, pyodbc contains C++ extensions so you will need a suitable C++ compiler on your computer to install pyodbc, for all operating systems.

See here: https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/

I suggest using the one form Microsoft Build Tools as suggested in your error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that since I'm so eager to see how python3.10 changes work and perform.

Comment: @ProsperPcyberBladeMawire If this or one of the other answers solved your problem, could you please set that answer as accepted? Like this other users can see if the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled the python upgrade from python3.10 to python3.9.5 and now I can enjoy using pip without any challenges.